# What is the right way to say "headache"?

Tags: словоупотребление

I have run across two terms, головная боль and болит голова. Do they mean different things, or are they used in different ways?

Answer (score 5):

They both mean the same but "головная боль" is more official, you hardly hear it in conversations. It's mostly "у меня (него/её) болит/болела голова" what people say, not "у меня головная боль".

Both can also be used in figurative way with meaning "to feel concerned about smth."

> *"У меня голова болит по поводу завтрашнего экзамена" - "I worry about my tomorrow's exam"*.

Comment: +1 Official language ("legalese") tends to avoid verbs and uses noun-like forms whenever possible. Natural speech tends to use more verbs.

Comment: "Головная боль" may also be used when talking about phenomenon itself, not bounded to any person. And for the second case, if something (or more probably someone) makes you worry regularly, you can say "Мой племянник — сплошная головная боль" ("My nephew is a constant worry and/or trouble").

Answer (score 1):

They mean exactly the same thing, `головная боль` is the headache, the `[у меня] болит голова` is `[I'm] having a headache`. The phrase `у меня головная боль` is, though grammatically correct, quite unnatural.

Comment: I don't see anything unnatural about "у меня головная боль". Вполне нормальная фраза.

Comment: "У меня ужасная головная боль", "некто страдал от страшной головной боли"- sounds a bit bookish, but not unnatural.

Answer (score 1):

Головная боль = headache ("головная" is an ajective and "боль" is a noun). Голова болит = (My) head hurts ("голова" is a noun and "болит" is a verb).

Yes, ones don't say "*У меня головная боль*" = "*I've got a headache*", you should say: "*У меня болит голова*" (more appropriate) or "*У меня голова болит*" (less appropriate).  "*У меня гловная боль*" is in 16 time less common than "*У меня болит голова*" due to Google search.

But it's normal to say in plural: "*У меня головн**ые** бол**и***" that means "*I have regular headache*".

Also I don't agree that "голова болит" figuratively means "worry", that means "tired, sick": "*У меня голова болит от моих соседей*" = "*I'm sick of my neighbours*"

Comment: Better use http://ruscorpora.ru/ for research. Google shows estimated counts, not real ones. If you prefer Google you may want to use https://books.google.com/ngrams - search in Google Books.

Comment: @AlexeyMurzin "I don't agree that "голова болит" figuratively means "worry"" - напрасно не соглашаетесь, как всегда всё зависит от контекста - "завтра передаём это дело в прокуратуру и пусть теперь у них *голова болит*". ""У меня голова болит" (**less appropriate**)" - тоже спорно. Это гугл так посчитал? Контекст, интонации, эмоции: "Вася, ну сделай уже потише, у меня голова болит!"

Comment: 1. C "документами" - да, но с "экзаменами" - нет. Но опять же, с "документами" это будет не волнение, это будет "...и пусть теперь думают, как решить проблему". 2.  "У меня голова болит" и "У меня болит голова" - одинаковы по сути (просто слова местами поменяны), но второй вариант как по мне немного удобней и судя по тому же гуглу чуть более популярен, что было сказано в виде more and less appropriate.

Comment: Да, пример с экзаменом мне тоже не очень нравится, но это субъективный взгляд. Некоторые люди действительно так говорят, и для них это совершенно нормальная фраза. Ваше "как по мне" тоже субъективно, на что я и обратил внимание. Если вспомнить про ОП (not Russian) и его/её вопрос, то он ведь ваше 'less appropriate' примет на веру.. А это более чем спорно. И по поводу "решить проблему" аргумент тот же: this perfectly translates into English as "we'll pass the file to them and let **them** *worry* about this". Так что в этом я Aliss'у поддержу.

Comment: Вообще-то я писал про фразу "голова болит" (от экзаменов/соседей), что означает "устал". Вы с этим не согласились взяв иную фразу - "головная боль". Но это другое. Тут да, тут "головная боль" = "worry and/or trouble" или простое и понятное "проблема".

Comment: Да и Бог с ним. Здесь чертовски неудобно общаться (а с мобильника и вовсе кошмар, когда отвечаю - не могу перечитать, на что отвечаю). Я тут не так давно, но уже бросается в глаза, что многие друг друга не могут понять по той же причине.. Размер комментов ограничен, редактировать по прошествии 5 минут нельзч - неудобно.